# Why does part of my javascript code isn't runnig correctly?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, haml

So when I press start button I get this output

> Init1

and this error

> Source map error: Error: Invalid URL: webpack://Packs.[name]/webpack/bootstrap
> Resource URL: http://0.0.0.0:3000/packs/js/application-50e3aceac3d862ba8b6d.js
> Source Map URL: application-50e3aceac3d862ba8b6d.js.map

Even according my code I have to get `"Init2"` and `"Init3"` too.

my `games.html.haml` view file:

```
%h1 Catcher game
%p Catch bloks which are failling
%canvas#main_canvas
=button_tag "Start!", class: 'start_button', onclick: 'Packs.application.start'
```

my `start()` and `init()` functions in `chatcher.js` file:

```
function start() {
    console.log("Init3")
    var eater = new BigBlock(20, "pink");
    var smallBlocks = [];
    setInterval(function() { game(eater, smallBlocks); }, 1000/16);
    addEventListener("keydown", function(key) { eater.move(key) } ); 
}



window.init = function() {
    console.log("init2")
    var canvas = document.getElementById("main_canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
}
```

my `application.js` file

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require("jquery")

export * from '../packs/games/chatcher'

$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("init1")
    window.init;
})
```

and lastly my `config/webpack/environment.js`

```
const { environment } = require('@rails/webpacker')

var webpack = require('webpack');
environment.plugins.append(
  'Provide',
  new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: 'jquery',
    jQuery: 'jquery/src/jquery'
  })
)

module.exports = environment
environment.config.merge({
  output: {
    library: ['Packs', '[name]'],
    libraryTarget: 'var'
  },
})
```

Thank you for helping. Have a nice day.

Comment: BY the way, output from Firefox. Chrome doesn't have that error, but still only `Init1`

Comment: If you want to invoke a function you need to add parenthesis. `window.init` is a reference to the function, but doesn't do anything on its own. `window.init()` invokes the function.

Comment: Why the mix of CommonJS modules and ES modules in `application.js`?

Comment: @Ivar I added brackets to `window.init` so now it is `window.init()`, but it still prints only `Init1`.

Comment: @onix [It shouldn't](https://jsfiddle.net/dc3wLobx/). If that is the case I assume you either should get an error, or `window.init` (as referenced from `application.js`) isn't what you think it is.

Comment: @Ivar, but it does. I mean, I don't have any other `Init()` function in my code. Also, could it be problem with exports? I'm new in Rails 6 and webpack, and for me it is hard to figure it out, how does this works.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with exports myself I'm afraid, but if `window.init` is referring to that function, it should work as demonstrated by the link in my previous comment. And if `window.init` doesn't contain any value at all, [it should throw an error](https://jsfiddle.net/myqLupgd/). If it doesn't throw an error but also doesn't log `"init2"`, then it either is executing a different function (one that doesn't have `console.log("init2")`), or there is some issue with logging (i.e. it doesn't log at all, it is filtered out, or it logs to a different place).